# Automate Printer Selection c# IDM API

Tags: c#, filenet, filenet-panagon

I am using IDM Desktop api to download a large number of  documents,in this there is a function available to print the document using

```
           IDMObjects.Document FnDoc;
           FnDoc.doPrint(IDMPrinterTypes.NativePrinter);
```

this is working correctly and i downloaded pdf creater(printer driver) which helps me to download those documents as tiff or pdf images,pdf creater allows me to stop prompting for filenames etc so that i can easily run it through my code,my problem is even if it may not ask for filename the printer selection window appears each time doprint is called,this is the default behaviour from viewer program.

Is there a way to automaticly click "Ok" on the popup window or anyhow skip the printer selection window.

http://pic80.picturetrail.com/VOL1901/12707114/22603895/408975667.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution code for this

```
         SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

which can easily send the enter key to any window started by application